# Shell script/swayidle: Storing values

Tags: linux, shell-script, wayland

I'm using [swayidle](https://github.com/swaywm/swayidle) to change the backlight brightness levels of my screen and keyboard when idling for too long. However when resuming I would like to change the levels back to how they were. This is the script I've written to run swayidle:

```bash
#/bin/sh

screen="50%"
keyboard=1

swayidle -w timeout 295 "screen=$(brightnessctl get) && brightnessctl set 1%" \
    resume "brightnessctl set $screen" \
timeout 300 "swaylock -f && hyprctl dispatch dpms off && keyboard=$(brightnessctl --device='platform::kbd_backlight' get) && brightnessctl --device='platform::kbd_backlight' s 0" \
    resume "hyprctl dispatch dpms on && brightnessctl set $screen && brightnessctl --device='platform::kbd_backlight' s $keyboard" \
timeout 600 'systemctl suspend'
```

This of course doesn't work as I cannot access the `screen` and `keyboard` variables from within the swayidle call so my levels are just set to 50%. Is there any way of achieving this that doesn't involve having to create a temporary file to store these values?

Comment: You could start a daemon then send a signal on resume, but why bother when a simple file will do the trick?